# Alternative way to take screenshot without android.View in Android

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I'm currently developing on an Android Dependency/SDK that allows users to capture a screenshot. I've implemented the following code, which is working fine for capturing screenshots of the visible UI:

```
View mView = getCActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
mView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
mView .buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap mBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
Window window = getCActivity().getWindow();
```

However, the issue I'm facing is that I want to capture the UI with a transparent background and treat it like a UI surface or a render UI texture view. In other words, *I want to be capture view in surface view, texture view, background transparent (Likely Flutter UI)*

```
android.view.SurfaceView
android.graphics.SurfaceTexture
```

Is there a way to modify my existing code or implement additional features so that I can capture the UI with a surface view, texture view or transparent background? Any guidance, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the media projection API.

Comment: @CommonsWare don't you think every time it will ask permission whenever I will try to take screenshot?

Comment: Last I knew, you only need to ask once per process invocation, not on every screenshot.

Comment: Do you want to capture your app's ui or any screen you see at the moment?

Comment: I asked between two, I could not guess...

Comment: @F.Mysir I want to capture app's UI

Comment: Unfortunatly with Java and XML Ui I can not help. With this library I had great success with my app I am designing https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable but is for jetpack compose

Comment: Android app UI: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/1695037303949.jpeg
when User shake then SDK will appear : https://www.linkpicture.com/q/1695037394422.jpeg
to Report Bug .  this is the example how currently screenshot is taken .

Answer (score 1):

For API level 26 and above, you can use [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) as follows:

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val listener = PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener { copyResult ->
    when (copyResult) {
        PixelCopy.SUCCESS -> //use bitmap as a screenshot
        else -> //handle error
    }
}
PixelCopy.request(window, bitmap, listener, handler)
```

Or in Java:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener listener = copyResult -> {
    switch (copyResult) {
        case PixelCopy.SUCCESS:
            //use bitmap as a screenshot
            break;
        default:
            //handle error
            break;
    }
};
PixelCopy.request(window, bitmap, listener, handler);
```

For `SurfaceView` (i.e. if you pass it as a parameter instead of `Window`) the lower bound is 24, not 26.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the UI with a transparent background and treat it like a UI surface or a render UI texture view, you can use below code example

```
public Bitmap captureUIWithTransparentBackground() {
SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(getCActivity());
surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(1);
surfaceView.setSurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture);

Canvas canvas = surfaceTexture.lockCanvas(null);
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
View mView = getCActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
mView.draw(canvas);
canvas.unlockCanvasAndPost(surfaceTexture);

surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
surfaceTexture.getBitmap(bitmap);

return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom SurfaceView or TextureView to render your UI and then capture the content of that view as an image

```
public class CustomSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public CustomSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // Handle surface changes, if necessary
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Render your UI on the surface
        drawUI(holder.getSurface());

        // Capture the content of the surface as a Bitmap with a transparent background
        Bitmap capturedBitmap = captureTransparentBitmap();
        
        // Now, you have the capturedBitmap with a transparent background
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Handle surface destruction, if necessary
    }

    private void drawUI(Surface surface) {
        // Implement your UI rendering logic here using Canvas and Surface
        // This is where you render your UI elements onto the surface
    }

    private Bitmap captureTransparentBitmap() {
        // Capture the content of the SurfaceView as a Bitmap with a transparent background
        Bitmap capturedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(capturedBitmap);
        draw(canvas);
        return capturedBitmap;
    }
}
```